# Collision detection problem

Tags: android, collision-detection

I am a novice in android. It's my first game, so I am trying to make a frogger clone.
I am getting a problem in collision detection. In logcat, even though the frog is not moving and not colliding anywhere, I still get a "collision detected" message. Also, if the frog collides, it is not responding.

Please help me find the problem.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
Game class

    private Frog frog;
    private FrogControl fg;
    private FrogControlY fg1;
    private MainThread thread;

    ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    ImageView imageArr[] = new ImageView[20];
    int id[] = { R.drawable.audi_r8, R.drawable.bike, R.drawable.bus,
            R.drawable.car, R.drawable.chrysler, R.drawable.cruise_bike };

    ArrayList<Vehicle> vh = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    ArrayList<VehicleReverse> vhs = new ArrayList<VehicleReverse>();

    public Game(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        frog = new Frog(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.frog), 100, 400);
        fg = new FrogControl(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.arrow), 250, 400);
        fg1 = new FrogControlY(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.arrow), 0, 400);
        int noOfCar = (int) Math.random() * 5;
        int totalCar = 3 + noOfCar;
        for (int j = 0; j < totalCar; j++) {
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            int[] LaneSelection = { 50, 150, 250 };
            int yValue = LaneSelection[y];
            int x = 0;
            int frogX = frog.getX();
            int frogY = frog.getY();
            int frogW = fg.getX();
            int frogH = fg.getY();
            vh.add(new Vehicle(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    id[y]), x, yValue, frogX, frogY, frogW, frogH));
        }

        for (int k = totalCar - 1; k > 0; k--) {
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            int[] LaneSelection = { 100, 200, 300 };
            int yValue = LaneSelection[y];
            int x = 300;
            vhs.add(new VehicleReverse(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), id[y]), x, yValue));
        }
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // vh.carmove();
            fg.handleAction((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            fg1.handleActionY((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            if (fg.isTouched()) {
                // fg1.setTouchedY(false);
                if ((int) event.getX() < (250 + (fg.getX() / 2))
                        && (frog.getX() > 0)) {
                    frog.frogShiftLeft();
                    // fg1.setTouchedY(true);
                }
                if ((int) event.getX() >= (250 + (fg.getX() / 2))
                        && (frog.getX() < 300)) {
                    frog.frogShiftRight();
                }
            }
            if (fg1.isTouched()) {
                // fg.setTouched(false);
                if ((int) event.getY() < (380 + (fg1.getY() / 2))
                        && (frog.getY() > 0) && ((int) event.getX() < 100)) {
                    frog.frogShiftUp();
                    // fg.setTouched(true);
                }
                if ((int) event.getY() >= (380 + (fg1.getY() / 2))
                        && (frog.getY() < 400) && ((int) event.getX() < 100)) {
                    frog.frogShiftDown();
                }
            }
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (frog.isTouched()) {
                frog.setTouched(false);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        fg.draw(canvas);
        fg1.draw(canvas);
        frog.draw(canvas);
        for (int j = 0; j < vh.size(); j++) {
            Vehicle o = vh.get(j);
            o.draw(canvas);
            o.collision();
            /*
             * if(o.collision()){ //Frog f = new
             * Frog(Bitmap.createBitmap(null)); //frog.remove(); /*Intent intent
             * = new Intent(); startActivity(intent);
             */
            // }
        }

        for (int k = vhs.size() - 1; k > 0; k--) {
            VehicleReverse v = vhs.get(k);
            v.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}


vehicle class:
package com.froggergame;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;

public class Vehicle extends Thread implements Runnable{

    private static final String TAG = null;
    public Bitmap bmp;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    Frog frog;
    FrogControl froggy;
    Vehicle vehicle;
    int frogX,frogY;
    int frogW, frogH;

    public Vehicle(Bitmap bitmap,int x,int y,int frogX,int frogY, int frogW, int frogH){
        this.bmp=bitmap;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.frogX=frogX;
        this.frogY=frogY;
        this.frogH = frogH;
        this.frogW = frogW;
    }

    public Bitmap getBmp() {
        return bmp;
    }

    public void setBmp(Bitmap bmp) {
        this.bmp = bmp;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getW(){
        return bmp.getWidth();
    }

    public int getH() {
        return bmp.getHeight();
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void carmove(){
        try {
            System.out.println("carmove");
            x = x + 5;
            if(x>=300){
                x=0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        setX(x);
    }   

    public boolean collision(){
        System.out.println(getW());
        System.out.println(getX());
        System.out.println(getH());
        System.out.println(getY());
        System.out.println("Froggy x pos"+frogX);
        System.out.println("Froggy width"+frogW);
        System.out.println("Froggy y pos"+frogY);
        System.out.println("Froggy height"+frogH);

        if((getX()+getW()>=frogX)&&(getX()<frogX+frogW) && (getY()+getH()<=frogY)&&(getY()<frogY+frogH)) 
        {

            //frog = new Frog(Bitmap.createBitmap(null));
            Log.v(TAG, "Collision Detected");
             return true;
        }else {
            //Log.v(TAG, "Not collided");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y,null);
        carmove();
        //collision();
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, "here's my code, find my problem" type questions aren't really appreciated here.  There is a lot of work to go searching through your code visually to see something that might be causing the problem when it would be faster and easier for you to attach a debugger to your working project and step through it to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything in response to what's returned by Vehicle.collision().

In render():

```
o.collision();
/*
* if(o.collision()){ //Frog f = new
* Frog(Bitmap.createBitmap(null)); //frog.remove(); /*Intent intent
* = new Intent(); startActivity(intent);
*/
// }
```